# Sort feature type order in FME KMZ writer

Tags: kml, features, fme-form, kmz

I have 4 feature types I am writing to a single kmz file using FME.  Currently, these feature types are written as folders in the kmz file and appear in alphabetical order.

Is there any way to sort these folders so a particular folder is always first regardless of the first character in the folder name?  I know there is a way to sort the features within each folder, but I cannot determine how to sort the feature types themselves within the document.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible :-(

It's been filed as an enhancement request (PR#27504) and does have a relatively high priority. The solution - when it is implemented - will likely be a parameter on the writer to determine order.

Answer (score 0):

if they are in alphabetical order, just name your folders with a numeric prefix :

```
01_foldername
02_foldername
```

and so one ...